# JavaScript chart dropdown

Tags: javascript, dropdown, dashboard

I am trying to make my drop down trigger a change in the chart for number of days but I keep getting an error
3plots.js:63

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'destroy')
at daysChanged (plots.js:63:17)
at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (Index.html:30:74)
```

Comment: Share what you had tried.

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit our question accordingly.